# Facebook Like and Send plugin flyout clipping

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, send, clipping, flyout

I am implementing a Facebook application that shown as a tab in a fan page.

The application has a product details page that has like, send and comments plugins.

The problem is when clicking on the send and like buttons, the flyout dialog (the window that pops after clicking the button) is clipped by the left edge of the iframe (The application is in right to left language).

From graphical design perspective, the location of the buttons can't be changed and scroll bars are not allowed. The application must be 520px wide, no more and no less.

Is there any option to control the position of the flyout to prevent its clipping? Is there any other way to prevent the clipping?

I searched similar questions here with no success.

Comment: Good question.  I wish I knew the answer for you.  Upvoted this q for you in hopes it will attract more attention.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since these buttons include HTML structure in your page, they are stylable via CSS. So you can move the popup dialogs with CSS.

### Some Code

If you take a closer look at the popups presented by facebook, you will see, that it has some styles attached to it:
[image: Facebook Styles]

The only thing you now have to do is moving this popup via CSS to the correct position.

For example: if you want to hide the comment popup of the like button completely, you can just use this CSS:

```
.fb_edge_comment_widget.fb_iframe_widget {
    display: none;
}
```

If you now want to move it, you cannot use `.fb_edge_comment_widget.fb_iframe_widget` since the element properties (set by JavaScript) will override your CSS. You have to use the span one element lower:

```
.fb_edge_comment_widget.fb_iframe_widget > span{
    right: 300px;
}
```

This code will move the popup by 300px to the left:

[image: Moved by 300px]

This is not the most beautiful solution (note the small arrow at the top of the box now points to nothing), but it works.

### Complete test code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <style type="text/css">

        .fb_edge_comment_widget.fb_iframe_widget > span{
            right: 300px;
        }

        #wrap {
            width: 650px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrap">
            <div id="fb-root"></div>
            <script>(function(d, s, id) {
              var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
              if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
              js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
              js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/de_DE/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=336384849737745";
              fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
            }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

            <div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.google.de" data-send="true" data-width="500" data-show-faces="false"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried moving a Facebook driven popup before?  Give me an example of the css name you'd use to position a facebook driven popup?

Comment: I must confess, I only hid these popup before. I try to get a code example together.

Comment: That is correct. Facebook moved the flyout into the iframe and therefore you cannot style it with CSS anymore.

Comment: @apfelbox really good answer, just saved me with a client! :D

Answer (score 0):

It's not an exact answer to your question. It seems you cannot control the flyout at all. I was happy to get rid of the flyout completely by putting my fb button code in a div that's only as high as the button and set the overflow: hidden. Then the popup's not visible at all.

```
<div class="fb-wrap">
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/YOURURL="false" data-width="200" data-show-faces="false" data-colorscheme="dark"></div></div>

<style>
.fb-wrap {
height: 36px;
overflow: hidden;
}
</style>
```